# Different clang-tidy-17 behavior locally and in CI

Tags: c++, continuous-integration, github-actions, lint, clang-tidy

#### The problem

I'm running clang-tidy on Ubuntu jammy locally and in GitHub Actions. The problem is that I get different behavior in these environments for the following code, where `MyType` is trivially-copyable:

```cpp
void MyClass::setField(MyType value) {
  field_ = value;
}
```

In GitHub Actions I get the following error from clang-tidy:

```
error: parameter 'value' is passed by value and only copied once; consider moving it to avoid unnecessary copies [performance-unnecessary-value-param,-warnings-as-errors]
```

Locally this error doesn't appear and if I apply the suggested change (by adding `std::move`), I get the following error:

```
error: std::move of the variable 'value' of the trivially-copyable type 'MyType' has no effect; remove std::move() [performance-move-const-arg,-warnings-as-errors]
```

#### Environments

clang-tidy-17 is installed like so:

```sh
wget -O - https://apt.llvm.org/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo add-apt-repository -y "deb https://apt.llvm.org/jammy/ llvm-toolchain-jammy main"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install clang-tidy
```

`clang-tidy --version` prints `Ubuntu LLVM version 17.0.0 Optimized build` in both environments, so it should be the same version of clang-tidy-17.

The command I run clang-tidy with is: `run-clang-tidy -p build -extra-arg=-std=c++17 -quiet <files to scan>` -- it uses the `.clang-tidy` config I have in the repository, so clang-tidy should receive the same arguments. The contents of the config are:

```
Checks: 'android-*,bugprone-*,google-*,modernize-*,performance-*,portatibility-*,readability-*,-bugprone-easily-swappable-parameters,-modernize-use-trailing-return-type,-readability-identifier-length'
WarningsAsErrors: 'android-*,bugprone-*,clang-analyzer-*,google-*,performance-*,portatibility-*,readability-*'
```

The compiler I use in both environments is GNU 11.3.0.

Why does this happen? For me it seems like the behavior I get locally is the right one and I would prefer to also see it in CI.

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of your GHA workflow in your question along with your `.clang-tidy` configuration. Thanks!

Comment: @Azeem Added the relevant information

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that an additional library that was linked to my code in CI but not locally influenced clang-tidy in this way. I'm still not sure what exactly changes that makes applying `std::move` more efficient, though.